# Inspecting request/response from Java/spring web service client

Tags: java, web-services, spring, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have a client written in Java using the Springsource toolkit (that is, the @Service attribute) that is talking to an external webservice (completely seperate, nothing to do with my company) via HTTPS. I'm getting an exception on the marshalSendAndReceive step, which states that the content-type is coming back as text/html instead of the expected text/xml - with the message "could this be an error message?"

The webservice itself is the public test for the next version of the service, and calling the live service from the same code works fine. This particular method I am calling works fine on the live system but not on the test system.

My hunch is that the request is not correctly formatted for the test system - although only the response should have changed in the schema according to the release notes - and this is causing the service to return an error that is incorrectly parsed by my client. I am getting this error with all requests, even those that (according to the release notes) have not changed.

I have tried to use Fiddler and Wireshark to inspect the traffic, but can't get Fiddler to see it at all (I suspect this is a problem using Tomcat in STS with a proxy) and Wireshark can't decode the HTTPS stuff (I don't have the keys). I can't use HTTP, as the external service returns 403 Forbidden if I try.

I'm not the original developer, and I'm not even a Java developer. I am an experienced .NET developer, so any analogies with that will be understood - otherwise, I am a dummy and phrase your instructions/questions/possible help accordingly. As instructed by my predecessor, I have created a JAR file from the WSDL using XmlBeans and added that as a referenced library but I can't be sure that I've done that correctly, or even what it is that that is doing. It doesn't appear to have a discernable effect on things.

How can I debug this problem, and verify whether it is a problem with my client or their service?

Comment: Have you set the `Accept` header on your request to be `text/xml` (or perhaps `application/xml`)?

Comment: I can't see anywhere that that is set - not in the configuration or the Java.

Comment: Turns out the webservice address I was left by my predecessor and the different address I was given by the service's support teaam were both wrong. Playing with 'add service reference' in VS2012 helped me find the correct address! Eric B's answer is correct though, my bungling notwithstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first goal would be getting Fiddler working.  It is difficult to debug in the dark.  However, where I get confused is when you discuss your client running in Tomcat in STS.  Is your client a webapp?

Have you tried other tools like [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/?utm_expid=56905-8) to validate that the service is responding to your requests as expected?

Comment: It is a webapp, but the communication I am interested in is the application talking to this external webservice. I'll take a look at SoapUI, I'd never heard of it before. I am under the impression that the webservice (big service, hundreds of users, public integration test after their own internal tests) is not at fault though.

Comment: SoapUI is just a client that allows you to do testing of a webservice based on the provided WSDL.  You can see the server's response as well as trace data if needed.  A great WS debugging tool.  It will, at the very least, allow you to inspect the return traffic and see if it conforms to your expected result(s).